# trying to write a script to run a command in a deep directory on entry to ssh

Tags: bash, macos, ssh

So I'm trying to write a script that will let me run a command to initialize some things. To be more specific, let's say I start in my home directory but to run this command I want I must be in a directory three folders deep into the home directory.

My script looks generically like this.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    cd home/path/to/final/directory/
    command
```

Now usually, when I cd to this directory I can run the command on the command line and everything works fine.

When I tried to use a script to do it, the command line throws an error saying that that command isn't recognized like the computer doesn't know where to look.

The temporary fix I used was making a symbolic link to the directory I wanted but I was hoping someone could help me so that when I ssh to this node this script can be run immediately so I will not have to go into the deep directory, run the command and leave again.

Comment: `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: Oops, I'll remove the tag.

Comment: what is the full error message you got? what do you meen "command isn't recognized"?
beter using full path when you use cd ... and then the command

Comment: The full error message I had was something like "command not found" . Essentially the same error you get when trying to run something on command line that is not sourced to the path environment variable. Like if I typed 'a' on windows command line it would say "a is not recognized as a batch command..." -- it is the same error but for sh

Comment: the command initializes an environment to use for physics analysis but I now know that it is important that the command be run in specific directories because if I have several different environments in the mother dir. then running the command globally will cause issues. Thus a script is not a good idea for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining full paths, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh    
cd $HOME/path/to/final/directory && /path/to/your/command
```

In this case, it will try to `cd` into your defined directory but if it can't find the dir it will not run the command, this because of the `&&`

To test before running the command you could do a `ls`, for example:

```
cd $HOME/path/to/final/directory && ls
```

Comment: The command itself is not listed inside the directory so I can't ls to see it. I had a discussion with an advisor and he said it is in some configuration file but we shouldn't be trying to run the command globally because then versions of the environment I'm trying to set up will clash. This would work if I had the command in there, I should have worded the question a bit differently. Thanks.